Axis camera RTSP streaming bitrate is not controllable
We are streaming our Axis camera via RTSP to Dolby for broadcasting (WHIP). We would like to limit the bitrate of the stream. We tried the "Variable Bitrate (VBR)" mode, but the bitrate is still very high. When there was no motion, the bitrate was around 2.5 Mbps, and it could reach up to 20 Mbps when there was motion. This is the pipeline we are using.
rtspsrc location=rtsp://username:password@10.11.11.12/axis-media/media.amp?videobitratemode=vbr latency=0 name=rtsp !
rtph264depay ! rtph264pay config-interval=-1 !
application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264

We wish to limit the highest bitrate to around 500 kbps. Therefore, we need to use the "Max Bitrate (MBR)" mode to limit the maximum bitrate to 500 kbps. Here is the pipeline we are using
rtspsrc location=rtsp://username:password@10.11.11.12/axis-media/media.amp?videobitratemode=mbr&videomaxbitrate=500 latency=0 name=rtsp !
rtph264depay ! rtph264pay config-interval=-1 !
application/x-rtp,media=video,encoding-name=H264

But what we found was that sometimes the bitrate will exceed the limitation, with the highest bitrate reaching around 1 Mbps. We are not sure why this would happen, as the bitrate should always be lower than 500 kbps.
If possible, we still prefer to use the VBR mode to save bandwidth, as long as the bitrate can be within 0-500 kbps depending on the presence of motion.
Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

That should be a question to Axis support?
